# Swift SPM Plugin accessing/writing files outside the SPM

Tags: swift, xcode-plugin

I am adding an SPM plugin that needs to update files in the main xcode project

```
@main
struct MyPlugin: CommandPlugin {

    func performCommand(context: PackagePlugin.PluginContext, arguments: [String]) async throws {
        let tool = try context.tool(named: "MyCodegen")
        let codegenExecutable = URL(fileURLWithPath: tool.path.string)
        let process = try Process.run(codegenExecutable, arguments: ["myArg"])
        process.waitUntilExit()
    }
}
```

The plugin currently doesn't do the work itself, but rather starts another process

```
@main
struct MyCodegen: ParsableCommand {
    
    func run() throws {
       // this code is in an SPM that is added to the main project
       // I need to write files to the top level project

       let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
       try "test".write(to: path, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

It looks like the process doesn't have permission to write files

```
You don’t have permission to save the file “x” in the folder “y”.
```